# Android : MultiChoiceModeListener not invoked inside ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, baseadapter, android-listfragment

For an ICS based application, I have created a ListFragment, which in turn uses a BaseAdapter implementation. I have enabled MultiChoiceModeListener() in order to display the Contextual Action Bar. But the issue here is that whenever I check the CheckBox or long press the Label(Both are in the View set in BaseAdapter), MultiChoiceModeListener implementation is not invoked at all. Any sort of help is much appreciated as I am completely stuck after trying many options!!!

```
public class ActivitiesFragment extends ListFragment {

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Entering onActivityCreated()");
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    this.setAdapter();
    this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

private void setAdapter() {

    HashMap<String, String> activities = DBAdapter
            .getInstance(this.context).getActivities();
    setListAdapter(new ActivitiesList(Util.sortByComparator(activities)));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiSelectionListener());

}

private class ActivitiesList extends BaseAdapter {
    // Other functions declared
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ActivityView view = null;
        String activityName = this.activityList.get(position);
        String colour = this.activities.get(activityName);

        if (convertView == null) {
            // ActivityView is a LinearLayout with CheckBox, Label and a Button
            view = new ActivityView(context, activityName, colour);

        } else {
            view = (ActivityView) convertView;
            view.setActivityName(activityName);
        }
        return view;
    }
}

private class MultiSelectionListener implements MultiChoiceModeListener {
    // implementation
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `ActionMode.Callback`. [You should read through these docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB), it's actually pretty simple to use.

Comment: I haven't tried ActionMode.Callback yet. But isn't this used for single views? What I am looking for is batch contextual action, where I have to select multiple views in this ListFragment. And I have implemented the same way it is mentioned in the android developer link.

Comment: `ActionMode` is used for batch selection.

Comment: you are wrong. MultiChoiceModeListener is intended for such a use. Look at List16 in API demos.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if nothing in your list has an onLongClickListener on it.
I had the same issue as you and I realized the long click was called by my ViewHolder so the MultiChoiceListener was never called.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in which even though the items listed in the `ListView` had a `CheckBox`, checking them would not invoke the `MultiChoiceModeListener`. Through some research and a look at the sample called `CustomChoiceList` (which you can import in Android Studio from `File`->`Import Sample`), I found out that the bound `View`s to the `ListView` must implement the interface `Checkable`. Directly quoting from the CustomChoiceList sample

> When a ListView has a choiceMode set, it will allow users to "choose" one or more items. The framework provides default list item layouts that show standard radio buttons or check boxes next to a single line of text:
>
> android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice and android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice.
>
> In some cases, you may want to customize this layout. When doing so, the root view must implement the Checkable interface.

I know that the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB) could be a bit more clear about the need for implementing the Checkable interface. It says though in the last paragraph that

> When a user selects the checkbox, you can invoke the contextual action
>   mode by setting the respective list item to the checked state with
>   setItemChecked().

You don't have to worry about `ActionMode.Callback` because it is handled by the `MultipleChoiceModeListener`

Answer (score -3):

Probably there is bug in your implementation of MultiChoiceModeListener.  It works fine for me.